# In what format does S3->getObjectInfo() return modified time of a file?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using the `getObjectInfo($bucket,$fileUri)` to get the details of the files I have on S3.
Now when I execute the function,I get a result as an array

```
  Array
  (
    [time] => 1384861952
    [hash] => c3c40e7df05a9d622bab85917d52abda
    [type] => application/pdf
    [size] => 331246
  )
  Array
 (
    [time] => 1384864779
    [hash] => f5cb8cf703e43f2929bef44286cd1e60
    [type] => application/pdf
    [size] => 503772
  )
```

I understand the size parameter would be in bytes and I have to convert it to maybe MB or KB.But the time attribute is a bit confusing.I am not sure if its the last modified time,because the name doesn't say that.
Also,the SDK(I use **PHP SDK**) function does not have a list of what the function actually returns.This is the function.

```
   /**
* Get object information
*
* @param string $bucket Bucket name
* @param string $uri Object URI
* @param boolean $returnInfo Return response information
* @return mixed | false
*/
public static function getObjectInfo($bucket, $uri, $returnInfo = true)
{
    $rest = new S3Request('HEAD', $bucket, $uri, self::$endpoint);
    $rest = $rest->getResponse();
    if ($rest->error === false && ($rest->code !== 200 && $rest->code !== 404))
        $rest->error = array('code' => $rest->code, 'message' => 'Unexpected HTTP status');
    if ($rest->error !== false)
    {
        self::__triggerError(sprintf("S3::getObjectInfo({$bucket}, {$uri}): [%s] %s",
        $rest->error['code'], $rest->error['message']), __FILE__, __LINE__);
        return false;
    }
    return $rest->code == 200 ? $returnInfo ? $rest->headers : true : false;
}
```

Does it actually return the **modified time** as it shows up on the S3 dashboard? OR it means something else?I need help to understand it.If its the modified time,what is the format(On the dashboard it add the **GMT+ difference** time)?The [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/dev/GettingObjectsUsingAPIs.html) is also not very clear.
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number value near time is the epoch time, just submit it to the date function and specify your format:

```
<?php
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", NUMBER_HERE);
?>
```

or

```
<?php    
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1384861952);
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1384864779);
?>
```

your two numbers return

```
2013-11-19 06:52:32
2013-11-19 07:39:39
```